# Structured instructions for simple extraction script

Tags: regex, perl

I have a rather simple task in trying to extract keywords from `input.dat` which looks like:

```
func1
{
        yes         true;
        keyword123  (1.1 0 -0.3);
        gamma       (0 1 0);
        dir         (1 0 0);
func2
{
        yes         false;
        keyword123  (1.1 0 -0.3);
        gamma       (0 0 1);
        dir         (1 0 0);
```

In this case I want to get the first entry in the vector of `keyword123`. If the lines containing the keyword aren't identically, the script should stop with an error. I feel that this should be a one- or twoliner in PERL using RegEx but it took me some time to get the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $path = "./input.dat";

# array @grepped of lines containing keyword
my @grepped=();
open(FILE,"$path") or die "error on opening $path: $!\n";
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
        if ($line=~ /keyword123/i){push(@grepped,"$line")};
}
close(FILE);

# get array @unique of unique lines
my %seen;
my @unique = grep {!$seen{$_}++} @grepped;

# continue with $unique if keyword-line is unique
my $unique;
if (scalar @unique eq 1) {
        $unique=$unique[0];
} else {
        die "entry not unique, exiting: $!\n";
}

# get string between brackets
$unique =~ /\((.+?)\)/;
my $final = $1;

# cut after first space
$final =~ s/\s.*//s;
print "keyword123: $final\n";
```

The script is giving the correct output but this can't be the best work, so any help/hint would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would implement it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;    

my $file = 'input.dat';
open my $IN, '<', $file or die $!;

my $uniq;
while (my $line = <$IN>) {
    next unless $line =~ /^\s*keyword123/;
    if (defined $uniq and $line ne $uniq) {
        die "Entry not unique. Exiting.\n";
    }
    $uniq = $line;
}
$uniq =~ s/.*\((.*)\).*/$1/;
$uniq =~ s/\s.*//;
print "keyword123: $uniq";
```

You can check the uniqueness each time you read the keyword line in. Once you find a non-unique line, you can stop right at the moment, no need to search the rest of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I beat it down to this (below). Since you didn't do anything with the other information you accumulated, I chose the early-out strategy.

```
my $k123;
open( my $fh, '<', './input.dat' ) or die "error on opening $path: $!\n";
while ( my $l = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $l;
    next unless $l =~ m/keyword123/i;
    $k123 //= $l;
    die "Entry not unique!" unless $k123 eq $l;
}
close $fh;
say "keyword123: ", ( $k123 =~ /\(([^)]+)\)/ );
```